# What does the word "obtained" here refer to?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> The findings of both studies support the further evaluation of the SCMS as a research and applied instrument, and suggest its potential current use in student and counseling settings given **obtained** relationships with anxiety, depression, and weight-management competencies.

I'm not sure whether the relationships here are obtained due to "the findings of both studies" or "student and counseling settings". Help?

Comment: The phrase **obtained relationships** (which is new to me) appears to be psychological jargon.  In your text, the phrase refers to existing conditions rather than arising from anything in the text. https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Obtained-relationships-in-Experiment-1_fig3_277060253

Comment: It might be referring to relationships demonstrated in the studies, in which case it should be "THE demonstrated relationships". It might help to post a link to the source document, if available online.